# C - Insertion in Linked List overwrite the values

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, binary-search-tree

I'm entering a linked list in a node belonging to a Binary Search Tree, that follows the following structure (without elements that do not involve anything in the problem):

```
// BINARY SEARCH TREE
typedef struct Equipo {
    char nombre[50];
    // [...]
    Lista *pilotos;
    struct nodo *izquierdo;
    struct nodo *derecho;
} Equipo;

typedef Equipo Arbol;

// LINKED LIST
typedef struct Piloto {
    int dorsal;
    // [....]
} Piloto;

typedef struct Nodo { 
    struct Piloto piloto;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Nodo;

typedef struct Lista {
    Nodo *cabeza;
    int longitud;
} Lista;
```

for the insertion of new `Pilotos` in the linked list, I use the function, that insert at init of list:

```
void InsertarCabezaLista(Lista *l, Piloto *piloto) {
    Nodo *n = CrearNodo(piloto); 
    n->siguiente = l->cabeza; 
    l->cabeza = n;
    l->longitud++;
}
```

For insert a `Equipo` its used the functions:

```
Equipo* CrearEquipo(Equipo *e) {
    Equipo *n = (Equipo *)malloc(sizeof(Equipo));
    strncpy(n->nombre, e->nombre, 50);
    strncpy(n->marcaMoto, e->marcaMoto, 30);
    n->puntuaciones = 0;
    n->derecho = n->izquierdo = NULL;
    return n;
}

void InsertarEquipo(Equipo **arbol, Equipo *e) {
    if (*arbol == NULL) {
        Equipo *n = CrearEquipo(e);
        *arbol = n;
    } else {
        // Los elementos menores a la izq, los elementos
        // mayores a la der.
        int comparado = strncmp(e->nombre, (*arbol)->nombre, 50);
        if (comparado > 0) {
            InsertarEquipo(&(*arbol)->izquierdo, e);
        } else {
            InsertarEquipo(&(*arbol)->derecho, e);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, are different ways to insert, since `Equipo` belongs to a Binary Search Tree and `Piloto` belongs to a linked list.

In `main` I create 2 nodes of Binary Search Tree (`Equipo`):

```
Equipo *equipo = (Equipo *)malloc(sizeof(Equipo));
strcpy(equipo->nombre, "Ducati Team"); 
strcpy(equipo->marcaMoto, "Ducati"); 
equipo->puntuaciones = 0;
Arbol *arbol = CrearEquipo(equipo);

strcpy(equipo->nombre, "Repsol Honda Team"); 
strcpy(equipo->marcaMoto, "Honda"); 
equipo->puntuaciones = 0;
InsertarEquipo(&arbol, equipo);
```

And later, 3 nodes of linked list (`Piloto`) and insert the `Piloto` in an `Equipo` by name from `Equipo`:

```
Piloto *piloto = malloc(sizeof(piloto));

piloto->dorsal = 99;
strcpy(piloto->apellido, "Lorenzo");
InsertarPilotoEquipo(arbol, "Ducati Team", piloto);

piloto->dorsal = 93;
strcpy(piloto->apellido, "Márquez");
InsertarPilotoEquipo(arbol, "Repsol Honda Team", piloto);

piloto->dorsal = 26;
strcpy(piloto->apellido, "Pedrosa");
InsertarPilotoEquipo(arbol, "Repsol Honda Team", piloto);

piloto->dorsal = 27;
strcpy(piloto->apellido, "Wallon");
InsertarPilotoEquipo(arbol, "Repsol Honda Team", piloto);
```

As you can see, the `Equipo` in Tree `Ducati Team` has 1 `Piloto`, and `Repsol Honda Team` has 3 `Piloto`.

The function used by this, called `InsertarPilotoEquipo` is:

```
int InsertarPilotoEquipo(Equipo *arbol, char nombre[], Piloto *p) {
    if (!arbol) {
        return 0;
    } 
    Equipo *equipo = ObtenerEquipo(arbol, nombre);

    if (equipo) {
        equipo->pilotos = malloc(sizeof(equipo->pilotos));
        InsertarCabezaLista(equipo->pilotos, p);
        equipo->puntuaciones += p->puntuacion;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

There is no execution errors. But when I get the information from Tree, I get:

```
----------------------------
Nombre: Ducati Team
Moto: Ducati
Puntuacón: 46
Pilotos: 1
----------------------------

  Dorsal: 99
  Nombre: Lorenzo
  Puntuacón: 46


----------------------------
Nombre: Repsol Honda Team
Moto: Honda
Puntuacón: 204
Pilotos: 1
----------------------------

  Dorsal: 27
  Nombre: Wallon
  Puntuacón: 68
```

As we see, only records the last `Piloto` in a Tree node. It looks like it's overwritten on every call of every node in the tree.

To rule out problems with printing, I show the function that prints the data:

```
void BusquedaPreOrder(Equipo *arbol) {
    if (arbol) {
        printf("\n\t\t----------------------------");
        printf("\n\t\tNombre: %s", arbol->nombre);
        printf("\n\t\tMoto: %s", arbol->marcaMoto);
        printf("\n\t\tPuntuacón: %d", arbol->puntuaciones);
        printf("\n\t\tPilotos: %d", arbol->pilotos->longitud);
        printf("\n\t\t----------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arbol->pilotos->longitud; i++) {
            ImprimirPiloto(i, arbol->pilotos);
        }

        printf("\n");
        BusquedaPreOrder(arbol->izquierdo);
        BusquedaPreOrder(arbol->derecho);
    }
}
```

It's called simply by `BusquedaPreOrder(arbol);`.

I think the problem is in the call of `equipo->pilotos = malloc(sizeof(equipo->pilotos));` in every `InsertPilotoEquipo` function, by tree. But I can't figure out why or what the solution is.

Comment: It is hard to see the root cause of this. However, there could be two possible errors.
1. Have a look at how you print the data. Maybe the lists are correct, but the print faulty.
2. You seem to be happy with the Equipo struct. Hence, you can compare InsertarEquipo with InsertarPilotoEquipo, and see if you find any differences in linked lists. I see you have not included InsertarEquipo here.

Comment: I've updated the post with functions that you miss @diaco. As you can see, when printing the data I simply iterate for each element and its nested list; the parameter `arbol->pilotos->longitud` indicates the length of the list, which is increased in each `InsertarCabezaLista` with l->longitud++;` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem checking if the tree list was initialized or not; if it was not initialized and if it was continued with it (before it was initializing it as new on each call):

```
int InsertarPilotoEquipo(Equipo* arbol, char nombre[], Piloto* p) {
    if (!arbol) {
        return 0;
    } 
    Equipo* equipo = ObtenerEquipo(arbol, nombre);
    // ImprimirEquipo(equipo);
    if (equipo) {
        if (!equipo->pilotos) {
            equipo->pilotos  = malloc(sizeof(equipo->pilotos));
        }  
        InsertarCabezaLista(equipo->pilotos, p);
        equipo->puntuaciones += p->puntuacion;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```